# Which storage mechanism will be more efficient?

Tags: file-storage, notes

Case 1: If I have one record, and create 1000 attachments to that record worth 1KB each. 
Case 2: In another case, if I create one attachment and zip all the files together. Assuming that zipping the contents will not save the storage.

Which storage mechanism will be more efficient? Does the Notes and Attachments record by itself consume any space?

Comment: Is your question purely about space or do you want to be able to retrieve your attachments individually as needed?

Comment: The question is about space. We can retrieve the file either way efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

If you were talking a regular Hard Disc, then obviously, Case 2 would be more efficient. However, with Salesforce, efficient use of disc space is the least of your concerns. According to the [Salesforce Limits Quick Reference Guide](https://na15.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf), for an EE Org, the file storage allocation is 11 GB, so I wouldn't see that as a concern especially since I see no limits placed on the number of files an org can store. Fast and easy record retrieval would seem to be of much more importance.